# How to display ONLY local country names in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, labeling

I am using google maps in an application where it is important that country labels display the country name in the local language.
If you pass in certain language parameters that google maps recognizes, but doesn't fully support (language=ka here), it displays localized place names with english labels underneath:

[image]

Which is great, except that I don't want the English labels at the bottom.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does not look like Google Maps create them single Language any more https://www.google.ge/maps/place/%E1%83%97%E1%83%91%E1%83%98%E1%83%9A%E1%83%98%E1%83%A1%E1%83%98/@42.0648059,45.0603944,8z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x40440cd7e64f626b:0x61d084ede2576ea3